# How do you reset the keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout, solaar

In Ubuntu 22.04 (with the standard desktop environment, just with Wayland disabled), I installed `solaar` for my Logitech keyboard. Then, some keys are changed, for example, (\ and `). The right Ctrl and Alt do not work.

I uninstalled `solaar`, and reset the layout to Generic 105 Key via `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but still no luck.

How can I remove the keyboard and add it like it is the first time to have the standard layout.

Comment: @vanadium it's the standard desktop environment of Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Indeed, then Gnome is superseding these settings: first check whether the keyboard layout in Settings is correct, then check the keyboard options that are exposed on the keyboard tab in Gnome Tweaks - some options may be turned on there that cause the undesired behavior.